# Is it possible to intercept & custom process stream chunks from fs.readStream?

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to process chunks of data midstream from fs.readStream?  Example: Read a file and count how many times a character occurs without storing the entire file in memory.  Simply parse each chunk from the stream and aggregate a number.. I tried creating a function to pass to .pipe() but the fn was required to have `.on()` defined and failed.

I'm a bit beginner at streaming.  I've done a bunch of googling, reading, experimenting but nothing has helped. I also can't find any info on how piping works or if you can make your own custom pipe receiver functions.

Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook ?

Comment: I have not -- I will now thanks

Answer (score 3):

The easies thing you could do is to just subscribe at 'data' event and simply count the occurrences like this:

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

const countCharsInString = function (st, char) {
 //Use a regex to calculate this
 let regex = new RegExp(char, 'g');
 return (st.match(regex) || []).length
};

const CHAR_TO_COUNT = '1';
let total_count = 0;

let fileStream = fs.createReadStream('./log.txt');

//We'll calculate the occurrences as the stream emits data event
//As we don't keep any references to 'chunk' and we don't collect the data anywhere
//The garbage collector will clean the memory and we'll not run out of the RAM.
fileStream.on('data', chunk => {
 let string = chunk.toString();
 total_count += countCharsInString(string, CHAR_TO_COUNT);
});
fileStream.on('error', err => console.error(err.stack));
//Log the count when everything is done.
fileStream.on('end', () => console.log(`All done. There are ${total_count} occurrences of character '${CHAR_TO_COUNT}'.`));
```

But if you want do do it via stream, aggregate the data on the fly and then pipe it somewhere else, here's what you could do:

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const Transform = require('stream').Transform;

//We inherit from the Transform stream class
class OcurrenceCountingStream extends Transform {
 constructor(options) {
  super(options);

  //Allowing to pass an option here
  this.charToCount = options.charToCount;
  this.totalCount = 0;
 }

 //This is now a static method as it's a pure function
 //That does not depend on the object state
 static countCharsInString(st, char) {
  //Use a regex to calculate this
  let regex = new RegExp(char, 'g');
  return (st.match(regex) || []).length
 }

 //We should implement _transform function
 //in order to make all piping mechanisms working
 _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
  //Get our string, process and update totalCount
  let string = chunk.toString();
  this.totalCount += OcurrenceCountingStream.countCharsInString(string, this.charToCount);

  //Pass the data further
  callback(null, chunk);
 }
}

let fileStream = fs.createReadStream('./log.txt');
let countingStream = new OcurrenceCountingStream({charToCount: '1'});

//So now we can pipe 
fileStream.pipe(countingStream);
/*
 Here is a little moment.
 The stream should be in a flowing mode. This means that is started reading the data
 From the writable that was piped to it and will keep reading until the writer is ended
 So nothing basically happens if we just pipe it like this fileStream.pipe(countingStream);
 There are some ways to make countingStream flowing:
 1) Subscribe on its 'data' event.
 2) Pipe it somewhere
 3) Call .resume() is we don't really care of the data that's comming out.
 */
countingStream.resume();

countingStream.on('error', err => console.error(err.stack));
countingStream.on('end', () => console.log(`All done. There are ${countingStream.totalCount} occurrences of character '${countingStream.charToCount}'.`));
```